# Dbeaver SQL Cast Convert

Tags: sql, casting, dbeaver

I am a beginner of SQL and I am using Dbeaver.

I connected Excel csv data to my Dbeaver working space and all the date format is string

So to do some work, I want some columns to be integer but cast and convert function doesn't work

```
Select Cast(total_cases AS int)

Select convert(int, total_cases)
```

These codes do not work at all..

Could anyone help me?

Comment: can you share the exact error its throwing

Comment: if I type. cast As function it says   SQL Error: Syntax error: Encountered " "AS" "as "" at line 1, column 21.
Was expecting:
    ")" ...

Comment: If I type Convert(int, total_cases) it says  SQL Error: Syntax error: Invalid column name: INT

Comment: How do you connect to the Excel csv data directly?

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue but the code below worked for me

select *
from coursesakl as ck
left join categoriesakl as cg
on cast(ck.categoryid as Integer)   = cast(cg.category_courseid  as Integer)
where cg.categorydesc = 'Java'

Answer (score 0):

no dbeaver use

cast(campo_ou_variavel as numeric(15,2))

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).